# pandas .txt file to .csv file missing lines

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to convert a .txt file into a .csv file. The .txt file consists of a list of words along with their POS tags in the form of:
Sophie_NNP listens_VBZ to_TO her_PRP$ classmates_NNS as_IN they_PRP tell_VBP her_PRP (and so on).

Using this code, I converted it into a csv file so that each word and its tag are on their own line:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

infile = 'POS_Test.txt'
Text_File = open(infile, 'r')

Table = 'POS_Text.csv'
output_file = open(Table, 'w')

for line in Text_File.readlines():
    text_list = re.split('[ ]', line)

sentences = pd.DataFrame(text_list)
print(sentences, file=output_file)

output_file.close()
```

This works fine, only the problem is that when I open the .csv file in Notepad++ or Excel, it seems to skip out lines 30 through to 540 (there are 571 in total) and replaces them with dots in one line.

[Screenshot of the area where the lines are missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz4nn.png)

Is there something I can add to my code that will prevent this from happening so that I can see every single line? Ideally in Excel as this is where the work will be continued.

As requested by Jan:
Here is the full .txt file:

B_IN The_DT dare_NN Sophie_NNP listens_VBZ to_TO her_PRP$ classmates_NNS as_IN they_PRP tell_VBP her_PRP about_IN the_DT dare_NN ._. She_PRP is_VBZ nervous_JJ ._. She_PRP does_VBZ not_RB want_VB to_TO do_VB the_DT dare_NN ._. But_CC every_DT new_JJ pupil_NN has_VBZ to_TO do_VB it_PRP ._. Every_DT day_NN on_IN her_PRP$ way_NN to_TO school_NN ,_, Sophie_NNP passes_VBZ the_DT old_JJ house_NN ._. It_PRP looks_VBZ terrifying_VBG and_CC everyone_NN says_VBZ it_PRP is_VBZ haunted_VBN ._. No_DT one_NN is_VBZ sure_JJ if_IN people_NNS live_VBP there_RB or_CC not_RB ._. People_NNS are_VBP too_RB scared_JJ to_TO find_VB out_RP ._. Most_JJS pupils_JJ never_RB knock_VBP on_IN the_DT door_NN ._. Only_RB brave_JJ children_NNS finish_VBP the_DT dare_NN and_CC knock_NN ._. again_RB :_: One_CD afternoon_NN a_DT young_JJ boy_NN is_VBZ bored_VBN ._. He_PRP wants_VBZ to_TO go_VB to_TO the_DT old_JJ house_NN ._. His_PRP$ parents_NNS tell_VBP him_PRP not_RB to_TO go_VB ._. They_PRP tell_VBP him_PRP it_PRP 's_VBZ dangerous_JJ ._. But_CC the_DT young_JJ boy_NN does_VBZ n't_RB listen_VB ._. When_WRB he_PRP gets_VBZ to_TO the_DT house_NN he_PRP knocks_VBZ on_IN the_DT door_NN and_CC waits_NNS ._. Nothing_NN ._. He_PRP knocks_VBZ again_RB ._. Finally_RB ,_, the_DT door_NN opens_VBZ ._. But_CC there_EX is_VBZ nobody_NN there_RB ._. The_DT boy_NN walks_NNS inside_IN ._. The_DT door_NN shuts_VBZ quickly_RB behind_IN him_PRP ._. The_DT house_NN is_VBZ dark_JJ and_CC it_PRP smells_VBZ disgusting_VBG ._. The_DT boy_NN hears_VBZ a_DT noise_NN ._. A_DT scratch_NN ._. He_PRP walks_VBZ along_IN the_DT hallway_NN ._. The_DT noise_NN gets_VBZ louder_JJR ._. Where_WRB is_VBZ it_PRP coming_VBG from_IN ?_. Suddenly_RB ,_, he_PRP trips_VBZ ._. His_PRP$ head_NN hits_VBZ the_DT wooden_JJ floor_NN with_IN a_DT B_NNP A_NNP N_NNP G_NNP !_. The_DT boy_NN lies_VBZ on_IN the_DT floor_NN ,_, shocked_VBD ._. He_PRP hears_VBZ the_DT noise_NN again_RB ._. Scratch_NNP ,_, scratch_NN ,_, S_NNP C_NNP R_NNP A_NNP T_NNP C_NNP H_NNP ,_, S_NNP C_NNP R_NNP A_NNP T_NNP C_NNP H._NNP It_PRP is_VBZ coming_VBG from_IN under_IN the_DT floor_NN ._. The_DT boy_NN is_VBZ too_RB scared_VBN to_TO move_VB ._. He_PRP wants_VBZ the_DT scratching_NN to_TO stop_VB ._. Finally_RB ,_, it_PRP does_VBZ ._. The_DT boy_NN slowly_RB stands_VBZ up_RP and_CC looks_VBZ around_RB ._. And_CC there_RB ,_, in_IN front_NN of_IN him_PRP ,_, is_VBZ a_DT dark_JJ figure_NN in_IN a_DT hood_NN ._. The_DT figure_NN stares_VBZ at_IN him_PRP ._. It_PRP says_VBZ nothing_NN ._. Terrified_NNP ,_, the_DT boy_NN runs_VBZ to_TO the_DT door_NN ._. It_PRP 's_VBZ locked_VBN ._. He_PRP is_VBZ trapped_VBN ._. A_DT cold_JJ ,_, white_JJ hand_NN grabs_VBD him_PRP ._. The_DT boy_JJ screams_NN ._. Nobody_NN ever_RB sees_VBZ the_DT boy_NN again_RB ._. People_NNS say_VBP that_IN sometimes_RB you_PRP can_MD still_RB hear_VB his_PRP$ screams_NN ._. Some_DT people_NNS say_VBP he_PRP is_VBZ dead_JJ ._. Others_NNS are_VBP not_RB so_RB sure_JJ ._. Sophie_NNP thinks_VBZ about_IN the_DT story_NN as_IN she_PRP walks_VBZ slowly_RB along_IN the_DT icy_NN path_NN ._. She_PRP reaches_VBZ the_DT garden_NN wall_NN ._. T_NNP H_NNP U_NNP M_NNP P_NNP ,_, T_NNP H_NNP U_NNP M_NNP P._NNP T_NNP H_NNP U_NNP M_NNP P_NNP ,_, T_NNP H_NNP U_NNP M_NNP P._NNP Her_NNP heart_NN beats_VBZ quickly_RB ._. She_PRP walks_VBD into_IN the_DT garden_NN ._. She_PRP shivers_VBD when_WRB she_PRP sees_VBZ graves_NNS by_IN the_DT path_NN ._. She_PRP tries_VBZ not_RB to_TO look_VB at_IN them_PRP as_IN she_PRP walks_VBZ up_IN to_TO the_DT house_NN ._. For_IN a_DT second_JJ Sophie_NNP thinks_VBZ she_PRP sees_VBZ a_DT dark_JJ figure_NN at_IN the_DT window_NN ._. She_PRP walks_VBZ slowly_RB to_TO the_DT door_NN ._. She_PRP knocks_VBZ and_CC waits_NNS ._. But_CC Sophie_NNP wants_VBZ to_TO be_VB really_RB brave_JJ ,_, so_IN she_PRP knocks_VBZ again_RB ._. She_PRP waits_VBZ ._. After_IN a_DT while_NN ,_, the_DT door_NN opens_VBZ ._. A_DT little_JJ old_JJ lady_NN looks_VBZ at_IN her_PRP ._. away_RB ._. I_PRP wonder_VBP why_WRB ._. anyway_RB ._. you_PRP are_VBP the_DT Then_RB she_PRP asks_VBZ Sophie_NNP to_TO come_VB in_IN ._. T_NNP H_NNP U_NNP M_NNP P_NNP ,_, beats_VBZ faster_RBR ._. She_PRP looks_VBZ behind_IN her_PRP ,_, then_RB walks_VBZ inside_RB ._. ("'", "''")

And the intended solution would be simply what is in the above screenshot, but instead of the ellipsis, you should actually see every single word with the POS tag - all 571 lines. This is the full Excel table I get at the moment:
[Excel result with ellipsis (Would like for the ... to be replaced through the actual words and POS tags)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njfet.png)

Comment: Please post an actual line from the file, and the intended solution. Or a link to example files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [df.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

What you are seeing is the middle of the dataframe sentence as displayed on the screen.

```
import pandas as pd
import re 

infile = 'POS_Test.txt'
Text_File = open(infile, 'r')

for line in Text_File.readlines():
    text_list = re.split('[ ]', line)

sentences = pd.DataFrame(text_list)
sentences.to_csv('POS_Text.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use Pandas for this? Seems like you can read the entire text file to a variable and split on the spaces.

```
import csv

with open('POS_Test.txt', 'r') as Text_File:
    split_values = Text_File.read().split(" ")

with open('POS_Text.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    wr = csv.writer(output_file)
    wr.writerow(split_values)
```

Edit - some more details:

First you want to open the files with 'with'. This ensures the files are closed after you are done with them.

Next you have the file contents (presumably as text) and you can simply perform the .split(" ") method on the string which would split on the spaces and give you a list containing many strings.

Then we open the output csv file with 'with' again and use the csv module [writerows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) to write the file out.

> writerows:
>   Write all elements in rows (an iterable of row objects as described
>   above) to the writer’s file object, formatted according to the current
>   dialect.

Comment: Later on I want to add columns with certain information. I have experience doing that with pandas which is why I chose it, but I can take a look at csv too, thanks! However, I get this error when I try your suggestion: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'. Any ideas?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @skytt4 my bad, I missed the .read() on the file object to read it into a string. Give this a shot!

Answer (score 0):

You can give list to pandas DataFrame

```
with open('temp.txt') as f:
    list = f.read().split()
    df = pd.DataFrame(list)
    df.to_csv('temp.csv')
```

Hope this helps!